# Error enter value in text field

Tags: html

When i entering data in text field(other then 1st text field) of my html it will automatically reach first text field in my html form

```
<form name="f" action="product.php" method="post">
                <td><h4><u>User Login:</u></h4></td>
                <tr><td >Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="user" class="style" placeholder="Enter UserName" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass" class="style" placeholder="Enter Password" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  /><input type="button" name="newuser" value="Newuser"onclick="self.location="Newuser.jsp"" />`enter code here`</td></tr>
</form>
```

Comment: i couldn't see any error in the code you have  provided. I think i should work just work fine.. check out http://jsfiddle.net/BUSmq/

Comment: Maybe you would like to explain you question in a better way.

Comment: i have two text field(1st username,2nd password) in that when i click 2nd field the cursor automatically ll go to 1st text field but if i use tab button its working

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? Works as expected for me.

Comment: it is happening in forefox 4.0.1 and chrome 19.0

Comment: it is happening in forefox 4.0.1 and chrome 19.0..its working in IE 8 but the watermark is not visible in IE browser....i have used placeholder attribute in <input> tag for watermark...

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are entering data in password before the page completely loads and when it does the cursor jumps to the username textbox, it being first in HTML. Happens with me often!